# What is CwZip1 and how do I extract the content

Tags: backup, zip

I got sent a backup file that is in CwZip1.01 format, anyone knows how to extract this

Comment: Which tools have you tried already?

Comment: Numeric sequences usually start with the 'correct' extension - ie CwZip1.zip, CwZip1.01, CwZip1.02 etc. You drop/run the first file, the rest get figured out in sequence.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I have used WinRar, WinZip and 7-Zip

Comment: @Tetsujin Its the header inside the file, not the sequence of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know CWZIP is an old (been at least 15 years since I last encountered this) compression library used by some software to internally compress their data-files.

These compressed data-files can usually only be opened/read by the program that made them in the first place.
It is normally not used as as a standalone compression format.

Ask whoever send you that backup how to open/use those files. They should know.

Comment: Thanks @Tonny - will have a chat to them